# A few questions about partitioning of disks

Tags: partition, partition-table

My storage device has GPT standard for the layout.

Wiki says, that each LBA has 512B size of sector.

[image]

This means, that I have to begin partition at:

```
LBA0+LBA1+LBA2+LBA3 = 512*4 = 2048B
```

or

```
LBA0 to LBA33 = 512*34 = 18KiB
```

or

```
LBA0 to LBA34 = 512*35 = 19KiB
```

And end partition at (total size minus LBA1 to LBA34)?

Comment: Just use {f,g}disk for the partitioning; it will handle the alignment.

Comment: OK and which software is so popular, that it will be almost on every Linux distribution? Thanks for answer, but for myself I would like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

The image you show labels the starting points of the different parts, and the zig-zag lines at the "Entries 5-128" box mean that the box isn't drawn to scale. It represents a block of 31 LBA sectors, but visually is drawn about 2-3 times the size of a one-sector block. The labels tell the true story, so the first LBA sector you can use for a partition is indeed #34 which is 34*512 = 17408 bytes from the start.

That doesn't mean you *should* start a partition there, however. With modern (large) disks having a physical block size of 4096 you probably want to start the partitions on a boundary that aligns with that. It's rather common to start at LBA 2048, i.e. 1 MB in, which is overkill for that purpose, but at least will not have any alignment issues in the near future.

Usually, the partitioning software you use will choose appropriate starting points for the partitions and make sure that you don't overlap other partitions or the partition table.

Comment: Thanks! I read a few articles and if I understand well. The 512B sector only uses old disks and each new uses a 4096B sector. HDD has one 4Kib physical sector and in this sector is 8x 512B logical sector. Right? So If I would like to enter size of sector manually, it will be 34*4KiB?